# Swift - Create consecutive date arrays from array of dates

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

So I have an array of `Date` objects, for example:

```
[2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000]
```

I have to split up this array into multiple arrays containing consecutive date ranges. The result should be like this:

```
[2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000],
[2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000], 
[2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000], 
[2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000]
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Swift?

Comment: What do you mean by "date ranges"?

Comment: why should it be split up like that?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I mean dates which are consecutive with regards to their day component should belong to the same array

Comment: @Sweeper basically I have a calendar on which I have to render dates which have an event added to them. Continuous days with events should look differently.

Comment: What are your data ? They seem to be Date description, not Date. So why aren't they between quotes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your `String` array is,

```
let arr = ["2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000"]
```

**1.** Get `dateArr` of type `[Date]` using `are`,

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateArr = arr.compactMap { formatter.date(from: $0) }
```

**2.** Sort the `dateArr` in ascending order,

```
let sortedDateArr = dateArr.sorted { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending }
```

**3.** You can now split up the `sortedDateArr` like so,

```
var result = [[String]]()
var tempArr = [String]()
for (index, date) in sortedDateArr.enumerated() {
    tempArr.append(formatter.string(from: date))
    if index+1 < sortedDateArr.count {
        if let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: sortedDateArr[index+1]).day, days > 1 {
            result.append(tempArr)
            tempArr = []
        }
    } else {
        result.append(tempArr)
    }
}
```

Comment: this assumes all dates don't have a time

Comment: @LeoDabus That’s what OP added in the question.

Comment: Btw this will fail to parse the dates if the device 24h time is set to 12h and there is no need to use a closure `arr.compactMap(formatter.date)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I just added the answer according to the OP's example. Time formatting will definitely needed to be changed if OP is more specific about it. That's just a way of how the solution can be achieved.

Comment: You need to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX". Feel free to keep the answer without it if you think thats not relevant.

Comment: It should be set before setting the dateFormat

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem! And thanks for the suggestions @LeoDabus

Comment: @chnski you are welcome. I have added an alternative that would work for any date regardless  of their times.

Answer (score 3):

You can create some helpers to get a time insensitive date and the date after a date to compare your dates for equality as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009988/2303865) and group the dates as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421092/2303865):

```
extension Date {
    var dayAfter: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)! }
    var noon: Date { Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element == Date {
    var grouped: [[Element]] {
        return reduce(into: []) {
            $0.last?.last?.dayAfter == $1.noon ?
            $0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1) :
            $0.append([$1])
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
let arr = ["2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000"]
let dates = arr.compactMap(Formatter.iso8601.date)
let grouped = dates.grouped
print(grouped)  // [[2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000], [2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000], [2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000], [2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000, 2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000]]

 // to convert the dates back to strings:
 let dateStrings = grouped.map { $0.map(Formatter.iso8601.string) }
 print(dateStrings)  // [["2020-09-07 00:00:00 +0000"], ["2020-09-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-09-16 00:00:00 +0000"], ["2020-09-23 00:00:00 +0000"], ["2020-10-12 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-13 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-14 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-15 00:00:00 +0000", "2020-10-16 00:00:00 +0000"]]
```